# Do default commands in Kendo UI's grid trigger events?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a standard delete command button in a grid.

I would like to subscribe to the event click for some check.

Can I do this? Or do I have to create a custom command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard delete command triggers the [remove event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-remove), so you can bind to that:

```
grid.bind("remove", function (e) {
    if (e.model.text === "Item 1") {
        console.log("well, I'm doing something else for you");
    }   
});
```

If you want custom behavior (e.g. create some logic to decide whether you want to allow this delete), then you'll probably have to create a custom command (you can style it in the same way if you want).